# Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "NumberManipulator"

Tags: c#

Код файла с классом `NumberManipulator`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

class NumberManipulator
{
    public int FindMax(int first, int second)
    {
        int result;

        if (first > second)
        {
            result = first;
        }
        else
        {
            result = second;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Код файла с классом `Program`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result;
            NumberManipulator numberman = new NumberManipulator();
            result = numberman.FindMax(30, 20);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
}

Сама ошибка:
Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "NumberManipulator" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGDe7.png
Версия с#: 1.24.4
```

Comment: текст ошибки какой? (добавьте в вопрос)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы пропустили код из файла `Program.cs` и текст ошибки

Comment: гадать сложно, но на 80% процентов есть уверенность в том, что вы забыли пометить метод `FindMax` модификатором `static`

Comment: Тогда ошибка не здесь, а в вызове. И лучше не делать static

Comment: Где находится код с классом NumberManipulator? В отдельном проекте? Приложите скриншот Обозревателя Решений (Solution Explorer). / Какая версия языка C# используется?

Comment: `namespace ConsoleApp1` в одном файле есть, во втором нет, а надо чтобы было

Comment: я добавил namespace, не помогает

Comment: также я пометил метод FindMax модификатором static, теперь присутсвует такая ошибка: Доступ к члену NumberManipulator.FindMax(int, int) через ссылку на экземпляр невозможен; вместо этого уточните его, указав имя типа.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте текст ошибки. Но тут можно предположить, что ошибка в переменной result. Вы её не инициализировали, а она не nullable. Проще сделать без неё:

```
class NumberManipulator
{ 
    public int FindMax(int first, int second) 
    {
        return first > second ? first : second;
    }
}
```

Comment: с `result` нет никаких проблем, так как и в `if`-е и в `else` переменной присваивается значения

Comment: [вот пруф](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M58BJf), что класс компилируется без проблем

Comment: Добавил текст ошибки и другой скрипт

Comment: Оберните класс в namespace ConsoleApp1 и попробуйте. Либо приложите скриншот из обозревателя решений

Comment: Добавил фото Solution explorer и написал версию c#

Comment: @Никита честно говоря никак не получается воспроизвести вашу ошибку. Самое время кидать гитхаб))